# Bootstrap column gets displaced into new row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap3 and using a collapsible element to in my design.

I am using 12 column inside the row as follows

```
<!-- Search Filter -->
<div id="search-filter">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">

        <!-- Collapse Search -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggle-search-filter" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#searchbar-collapse-set"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> </button>
        <!-- /Collapse Search -->

        <h3>Showing 345 Results <small>(Hill Stations around Bangalore)</small></h3>

      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="searchbar-collapse-set">

        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="distance">
            <h5>distance:</h5>
            <div id="distance-slider"></div>
            <span class="distance-value">250 kms</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
          <div class="sort">
            <h5>sort:</h5>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">popular</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">name</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">distance</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

      <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Search Filter -->
```

[image]

Due to the Collapsible element i the third column is shifting to the next row.

I removed the NavCollapse padding to 0 and the content disappears from the drop down as bellow.

[image]

By Adding the following code it gets back into place as bellow.

[image]

But it Disrupts the full screen view as bellow.

[image]

[Nomad Link](http://nomadapp.in/html/index.html)

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't remove the padding using a media query?

Comment: @joshhunt ahhhhh :( horrible time to code is when ur tired :(

Comment: @joshhunt thanks alot, you saved my braincells :D

Comment: Haha no worries, I'll put up a quick answer for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a media query such as

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

so that you can add the padding on a desktop display without effecting the display on smaller devices.

Comment: i need the padding in larger screens. smaller screens i need to remove it

Comment: @HarshaMV My mistake, fixed the wording. Did you get it working?